# SwiftUI Resizable rectangle by user with corners

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to make a text scan function and for that I need a rectangle which user could resize by dragging it by its corners. The idea is same like in photomath.

I've this code with this rectangle UI but I can't figure out how I could make it possible for user to resize it.

It should look like this and be resizable: [image: should look like this]

Here is my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ViewCamera: View {
        var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                let cutoutWidth: CGFloat = min(geometry.size.width, geometry.size.height) / 1.5

                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.black.opacity(0.5))
                        
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .fill(Color.black)
                        .frame(width: cutoutWidth, height: cutoutWidth, alignment: .center)
                        .blendMode(.destinationOut)
                }.compositingGroup()
                
                Path { path in
                    
                    let left = (geometry.size.width - cutoutWidth) / 2.0
                    let right = left + cutoutWidth
                    let top = (geometry.size.height - cutoutWidth) / 2.0
                    let bottom = top + cutoutWidth
                    
                    path.addPath(
                        createCornersPath(
                            left: left, top: top,
                            right: right, bottom: bottom,
                            cornerRadius: 40, cornerLength: 20
                        )
                    )
                }
                .stroke(Color("AccentColor2"), lineWidth: 8)
                .frame(width: cutoutWidth, height: cutoutWidth, alignment: .center)
                .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
            }
        }
        
        private func createCornersPath(
            left: CGFloat,
            top: CGFloat,
            right: CGFloat,
            bottom: CGFloat,
            cornerRadius: CGFloat,
            cornerLength: CGFloat
        ) -> Path {
            var path = Path()

            // top left
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: left, y: (top + cornerRadius / 2.0)))
            path.addArc(
                center: CGPoint(x: (left + cornerRadius / 2.0), y: (top + cornerRadius / 2.0)),
                radius: cornerRadius / 2.0,
                startAngle: Angle(degrees: 180.0),
                endAngle: Angle(degrees: 270.0),
                clockwise: false
            )

            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: left + (cornerRadius / 2.0), y: top))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: left + (cornerRadius / 2.0) + cornerLength, y: top))

            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: left, y: top + (cornerRadius / 2.0)))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: left, y: top + (cornerRadius / 2.0) + cornerLength))

            // top right
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: right - cornerRadius / 2.0, y: top))
            path.addArc(
                center: CGPoint(x: (right - cornerRadius / 2.0), y: (top + cornerRadius / 2.0)),
                radius: cornerRadius / 2.0,
                startAngle: Angle(degrees: 270.0),
                endAngle: Angle(degrees: 360.0),
                clockwise: false
            )

            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: right - (cornerRadius / 2.0), y: top))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: right - (cornerRadius / 2.0) - cornerLength, y: top))

            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: right, y: top + (cornerRadius / 2.0)))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: right, y: top + (cornerRadius / 2.0) + cornerLength))

            // bottom left
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: left + cornerRadius / 2.0, y: bottom))
            path.addArc(
                center: CGPoint(x: (left + cornerRadius / 2.0), y: (bottom - cornerRadius / 2.0)),
                radius: cornerRadius / 2.0,
                startAngle: Angle(degrees: 90.0),
                endAngle: Angle(degrees: 180.0),
                clockwise: false
            )
            
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: left + (cornerRadius / 2.0), y: bottom))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: left + (cornerRadius / 2.0) + cornerLength, y: bottom))

            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: left, y: bottom - (cornerRadius / 2.0)))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: left, y: bottom - (cornerRadius / 2.0) - cornerLength))

            // bottom right
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: right, y: bottom - cornerRadius / 2.0))
            path.addArc(
                center: CGPoint(x: (right - cornerRadius / 2.0), y: (bottom - cornerRadius / 2.0)),
                radius: cornerRadius / 2.0,
                startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0.0),
                endAngle: Angle(degrees: 90.0),
                clockwise: false
            )
            
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: right - (cornerRadius / 2.0), y: bottom))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: right - (cornerRadius / 2.0) - cornerLength, y: bottom))

            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: right, y: bottom - (cornerRadius / 2.0)))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: right, y: bottom - (cornerRadius / 2.0) - cornerLength))

            return path
        }
    }

struct ViewCamera_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ViewCamera()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a custom view that shows the Rectangle with properties of size and position and then add DragGesture to resize the rectangle when its is being resized by the user

```
struct ResizableRectangle: View {
@State private var size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
@State private var startPosition: CGPoint = .zero
@State private var resizing = false

var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.blue.opacity(0.3))
        .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    if !resizing {
                        startPosition = value.location
                        resizing = true
                    }
                    let delta = CGSize(
                        width: value.location.x - startPosition.x,
                        height: value.location.y - startPosition.y
                    )
                    size = CGSize(
                        width: max(50, size.width + delta.width),
                        height: max(50, size.height + delta.height)
                    )
                    startPosition = value.location
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    resizing = false
                }
        )
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .border(Color.blue)
}
```

}